# QImage creation

Tags: image, format, qimage

I start to work with images in radiolocation field using Qt library and I have some questions, sorry for stupid. I have to create black and white QImage from bytearray with 0 and 1 such this

```
0000000000000000000000

0000001100000000000000

0000001111000000000000

0000011111110000000000

0000011111111110000000

0000000111111111000000
```

I do

```
QImage pIm = QImage ((uchar *)(bIm.constData(), width, height, nBitsPerLine, QImage::Format_Mono);
```

where 0 is black color and 1 is white but image is incorrect, which way I have to transform colors on this image ? Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I transform these data onto pixels such this

```
QImage pIm (nWidth, nHeight, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
ncount = 0;
for (uint i=0; i<nWidth; i++)
{
    for (uint j=0; j<nHeight; j++)
    {
        uint c = (uchar)imData[ncount++];
        c *= 255;
        pIm.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(c,c,c));
    }
}
```

Before I think that pixels color can be described by normalized to 1.0 numbers, but my suppose was not correct and I transform to 0-255 range.